# How to create dynamic class with Angular2's ngClass?

Tags: javascript, angular, markup, ng-class

Say in the object models in my cloud Array I have a weight key:

```
return [
    {
        term: '1994',
        weight: 0
    },
    {
        term: '2017',
        weight: 0
    },
    {
        term: '89th',
        weight: 5
    }
```

What I want to do is use that weight to create a dynamic class in the markup. Ie: `cloud0`, `cloud9` etc...

How would that be done? Below is the code I tried and error I got.

---

```
<span *ngFor="let tag of cloud" [ngClass]="'cloud{{ tag.weight }}'">
    {{ tag.term }}
</span>

<!-- <span class="cloud0">1994</span>
<span class="cloud0">2017</span>
...
```

[image]

> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 6 in ['cloud{{ tag.weight }}'] in EntityComponent@72:56 (": 100%; min-height: 200px;" id="wordcloud">
>                           ][ngClass]="'cloud{{ tag.weight }}'">
>                               {{ tag.term }}
>                        "): EntityComponent@72:56
>   Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 6 in ['cloud{{ tag.weight }}'] in EntityComponent@72:56 ("cloud">
>                           [ERROR ->]
>                               {{ tag.term }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use just html `class` attribute:

```
<span *ngFor="let tag of cloud" class="cloud{{ tag.weight }}">
    {{ tag.term }}
</span>
```

There's no need to use ngClass on this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span *ngFor="let tag of cloud" [ngClass]="'cloud '+tag.weight">
    {{ tag.term }}
</span>
```